# MSAL for Python. Ocasionally getting error "AADSTS50196: The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop"

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

We have daemon application which reads e-mail from MS365. App reads dozen of mailboxes. Error hapens on very few mailboxes and ocassionally. When second server takes responsibility of mail reading, mails are fetched. If second server fails to fetch mails and first one takes mail reading task, reading mail works. Never able to reproduce.
Application is multithreaded. Exclusive lock was added to prevent multhithreaded access. Problem occures when token expires and application calls `acquire_token_by_username_password` . Specified scope is 'Default'. Error message:

```json
{
'error': 'invalid_grant',
'error_description': 'AADSTS50196: The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop. Please contact your app vendor'
}
```

If grant would be invalid, it should fail always.
This is long running problem. Customer upgraded MSAL library but it did not help.
Any suggestion in which direction to go to solve problem?
UPDATE:
It is possible to reproduce problem.

1. Make loop and call `acquire_token_by_username_password` inside loop
2. Wait up to 10 seconds
3. Next loop

After 20 attempts you will get `AADSTS50196` error. If you increase wait time to 30 seconds, you can run loop about 35 times. Increasing wait time increases number of requests.
**But if you recreate PublicClientApplication**, after every wait, no error. You can ran authentication request as many times as you like.
There is something in request what identifies app.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your request is being throttled which is due to making too many request in a short period of time. This can be mitigated by reducing the number of tokens you are requesting, and or ensuring that you are retrieving tokens from the cache. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#march-2019).

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/547).

Comment: I emphasized in question that app is multithreaded but app uses exclusive lock. If there is outstanding authenthication request, no other requests are made. App uses ROPC and queries dozen of mailboxes. I anticipated that tokens may expire in the same time and when polling, it could happen that every mailbox token will expire. Purpose of adding lock was to avoid parallel requests. Even with queued requests, error hapens on few mailboxes. I am not sure does order of mailboxes influence failure scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer here was right that this AADSTS50196 error means your app was sending too many requests in short time, thus being throttled. But this behavior on service side is a feature, not a bug. (That bug link was from MSAL.js library. The OP was using MSAL Python, so that is not applicable, either.)

@zdenko.s you mentioned your app is multithreaded with exclusive lock. But that would only guarantee your app won't send out concurrent requests, but it does not mean you won't get throttled. As your repro step shows, a (single thread?) sample app sending too many sequential requests in short time would get throttled, as expected.

Your exclusive lock should not just guard the `acquire_token_by_username_password()`. You should also put `acquire_token_silent()` inside the exclusive lock, if you haven't already. That way, only one thread would need to acquire a new token, and all subsequent threads would be able to reuse that token.

By the way, you should consider using `acquire_token_interactive()`. That way, your app does not need to get a hold of user's password.

Comment: Lock blocks whole authenthicatin chain. When token is acquired, lock is released. It is daemon application without interactive user.

Comment: Did your app use `acquire_token_silent()`? If not, you should. It reads and reuses existing tokens from cache, therefore avoid getting throttled. There is a sample for it in msal Python github repo.

Comment: Of course it uses. First step is to acquire token silent. If token is not available, acquire it. There is starnge behaviour here. One of dozen of mailboxes does not get "silent" token and code authenticates again. This causes the problem since app polls mailboxes every minute and Azure AD rejects flood of auth requests for this single mailbox.

Comment: "One of dozen of mailboxes does not get "silent" token and code authenticates again. This causes the problem since app polls mailboxes every minute and Azure AD rejects flood of auth requests for this single mailbox." Sounds like that was the root cause here. I'd suggest you use [the minimal sample app provided by MSAL Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/tree/dev/sample) to reproduce the issue with that one mailbox, and then post your new question either here or in the github.